# what is problem npm WARN deprecated tar@2.2.2: This version of tar is no longer supported, and will not receive security updates

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

please carefully answer All commands use below but no resolve answer..what is wrong?

```
**npm audit fix --force
npm uninstall -g create-react-app
Also removed the create-react-app manually from node modules folder.
npm install -g create-react-app@latest
npx create-react-app name gives below error
npm fund
npm audit **


C:\Users\Triotree>npm install -g create-react-app@latest
npm WARN deprecated tar@2.2.2: This version of tar is no longer supported, and will not receive security updates. Please upgrade asap.

changed 67 packages, and audited 68 packages in 12s

4 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

2 high severity vulnerabilities

Some issues need review, and may require choosing
a different dependency.
```